# I am trying to get the word "tech" to only apear once the page is scrolled The scroll function words but it is also at the top onload i dont want this

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the link to my website https://avandor.co.uk

This is my css:

````
```    .tech-header {
    padding-top: 17px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #A8A8A8;
    font-style: italic;
    z-index: 20;
    position: relative;
    left: -8px;
    top: -70px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}



.tech-header.tech {
    top: 0px;
}```
````

This is my JS

````
```
var mql = window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 950px)")

if (mql.matches){ // if media query matches

        const header = document.querySelector('.header');

        const tech = document.querySelector('.tech-header');

            window.onscroll = function(){
            var top = window.scrollY;
        
            if (top >= 800){
                

header.classList.add('active')
            
}else

{
                header.classList.remove('active')
            }
                if (top >= 1300){
               
 tech.classList.add('tech')
           
 }

else

{
                tech.classList.remove('tech')
            }
    
}

}

else{

    const header = document.querySelector('.header');

    const tech = document.querySelector('.tech-header');


        window.onscroll = function(){

        var top = window.scrollY;
    
        if (top >= 150){

            header.classList.add('active')

        }else{

            header.classList.remove('active')

        }

            if (top >= 500){

            tech.classList.add('tech')

        }else{

            tech.classList.remove('tech')
        }
        
    }
}
```
````

If you look at my website that I have linked you will see that the word 'tech' sits at the top on the nav bar next to the logo, then when you scroll down a couple of pixels it goes away.

I want it to be hidden until the page is scrolled down far enough for it to move from the top down to be next to the logo.

I hope this makes sense! Any questions please ask, Thanks for any help you can provide me in advance!

I usually work with css, javascript is new to me, I have got most things working right just this one part doesn't do what I want :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initially the correponding element has the tech class

```
<h1 class="tech-header tach" id="t-navbar">TECH</h1>
```

remove the 'tech' class from your html. html should look like:-----

```
<h1 class="tech-header" id="t-navbar">TECH</h1>
```

hope it will work.....:)

Answer (score 0):

i would try a different approach with initial display none and changing that in javascript first line after initializing tech

```js
const tech = document.querySelector('.tech-header');
tech.style.display="block";
function moveDivDown() {
tech.classList.add('tech')

}

function moveDivUP() {
tech.classList.remove('tech')

}
```

```css
.tech-header {
position: fixed;
top:-70px;
display:none;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.tech{
top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tech-header">hello</div>
</br>
</br>
<button onclick="moveDivDown()">Down</button>
<button onclick="moveDivUP()">UP</button>
```